# how to unit test an arrow function in angular 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine

here is the ts file i need to test, the uncovered code in Karma is only the below line

```
(value => {
      this.value = ++this.value;
    });
```

I am new to angular and completely new to unit testing, please help

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolHandlerService } from '../shared/services/toolhandler.service';
import { ISubscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'basic-graphicresults',
  templateUrl: './graphicresults.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graphicresults.component.scss']
})
export class GraphicResultsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() value: number;
  private replaceResultsSubscription: ISubscription;

  constructor(private toolHandlerService: ToolHandlerService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.value=4;
    this.replaceResultsSubscription = this.toolHandlerService.onReplaceResults$.subscribe(value => {
      this.value = ++this.value;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.replaceResultsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a mock class of ToolHandlerService class in the spec file and inject it to your testbed configuration providers like

```
providers: [{provide:ToolHandlerService, UseClass: MockToolHandlerService}]
```

and then in your testcase do this:

```
let isEventTriggered = false;
toolHandlerService.onReplaceResults$.subscribe(() => {
  isEventTriggered = true;
});
toolHandlerService.replaceResults.next();
expect(isEventTriggered).toBeTruthy();
```

By doing the above you will see the usecase will get covered.

Note: Here ToolHandlerService being used should hold the reference of MockToolHandlerService

Comment: Do you have any Idea in how to test properties like this: ```cellRenderer: params => {
            if (params.value != ' ') {
                var twoDigitsCurrentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2));
                var dateData = moment(params.value).format('M/D');
                return (dateData + "/" + twoDigitsCurrentYear);
            }
            else {
                return params.value;
            }
        }```

Comment: You can create a mock object with dummy values and use it to test the actual and expected output by passing it in the method or subscription.